# Unique constraint in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

How can one set some attribute in Entity (Entity Framework) to be unique? One possibility would be to make it primary key but that's not what I want.

Comment: [Entity 6.1 now supports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378448/3231778) this feature.

Comment: [Index(IsUnique = true)]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support unique keys so the only way is to set the unique constraint / index in the database. It will not ensure uniqueness in the application when you try to insert / update records but the exception will be fired if you try to save non unique value to the database.

Comment: It does now since v6.1. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378448/28098

Comment: @z-boss: Beware that it is not exactly what OP may asked for. There is a difference between uniqueness in the database and in the application. Supporting unique index through data annotations will still not ensure unique value handling in the application: eg. doesn't allow using relations with unique column as primary key in the application.

Comment: I needed exactly what OP wrote - ensure unique values in a column, which is not intended to be used as a key. EF v6.1 lets you specify such index as attribute now. BUT, you cannot add WHERE is not null clause. (Because I want to ensure uniqueness only for records that contain values). So, ended up creating index with SQL statement in migration.

Answer (score 6):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

also see
[Unique keys in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614941/unique-keys-in-entity-framework-4)

Comment: Yes, very nice article about feature we can hopefully expect in the next major release of Entity Framework - not in 4 or 4.1.

Comment: It seems this is not even included in EF v5 :(

Comment: And also not in EF6 :(

Comment: While the unique key cannot be added using a simple attribute. In Code First you can use the .Index() method to add the index in the migration class.