# How to handle two entities with one “unique” property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

I have these entities:

```
public class User {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    // OtherProperties
}

public class Page {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    // OtherProperties
}
```

`OtherProperties` are completely different in each entity from another one. But, `Username`s should be unique, no matter where they belong. I mean if there is a `User` with `Username = a`, none of other `User`s or `Page`s can have this `Username`. How would you handle this? Is it a good idea to have a 3th entity e.g. a

```
class Username { string Name { get; set; } }
```

considering this fact that it is just a simple-single property?

**UPDATE:** more explain:

`User` is a completely independent different entity from `Page`. But both of them have a property named `Username` which should be unique in entire application.

Comment: Your approach would be good.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal What approach? Creating a 3th class?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Would you post your comment as an answer? So I can +1 it or probably accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is good. Create a third class `Username` and add a property of it in your first two classes. Like this

```
class UserName
{
    string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class User
{
    public Username UName { get; set; }
    // OtherProperties
}

public class Page 
{
    public UserName UName { get; set; }
    // OtherProperties
}
```

Changed property name because class Name and property name was same. You can have what suits you best.

Back to problem.
Moreover tomorrow if you want to add any other details about User Name, then you have to add a property in your `UserName` and your code in User and Page will not require any change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unique user names in many classes then you should implement 3rd table with unique usernames which will be FKyed to all of the tables containing username property (column). For this task you can use class attributes or FluentAPI. As my experience told me it is better to use FluentAPI as attributes approach not always provide expected results.

For example smth like this:

```
public class Username
{
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Page> PagesList{ get; set; }
}

public class Page {
    public int UsernameId { get; set; }
    // OtherProperties
    public virtual string Username {get;set;}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Page>().HasRequired<Username>(s => s.Username)
        .WithMany(s => s.PagesList)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

More details on FluentAPI unique keys: [Unique keys in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614941/unique-keys-in-entity-framework-4)

More details on implementing FKs: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: No this is not what I mean. `User` is a completely different entity from `Page`. But both of them have a property named `Username` which should be unique in entire application.

Comment: Then you shoud make 3rd table that is common for both of them.

Comment: OK. I updated the question too. If you think I should do that, post it as your answer - or update the current one - so I can +1 it. I'll wait for a while for other suggestions, and I will accept the best one.